# Should we add a new [Oracle-21c] tag?

Tags: discussion

Does DBA SE need a new Oracle-21c tag?

I see tags for older versions of Oracle. But I don't see one for version 21c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New tags get added when they're needed.

There's no way to create a tag without a question to attach it to.

As soon as an Oracle 21c question is posted, one of the users with the ability to create the tag will do so.

---

As you have now provided [an example question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/305548), I have created the tag.